# How to configure a container in flutter to use the same height of an other children in the same row or column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I like to increase the height of the widget "B" so the orange color use the same space like the green color. I have added a code example.
If a added Extended() like Expanded(Container(Text('B'))) the full horizontal space of the screen is used.
If a added Extended() like Column(Expanded(Container(Text('B')))) the full vertical space of the screen is used.

Does someone has a hint?
Thank you in advance!

Gretings

Michael

Problem:

[image]

Goal:

[image]

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(DemoX());
}

class DemoX extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.green,
                  child: Text('A1\nA2'),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.orange,
                child: Text('B'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Text('A1\nA2'),
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
              child: Text('B'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to wrap Row with IntristicHeight? Congrats on reaching 100k from this upvote though

Comment: @Uni You need to do so otherwise the Row will expand (in cross axis) to fill up the available space (screen size in the code above), either you provide some fixed height or use `IntrinsicHeight`. Thanks :)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks for helping the community out. You've written so many good answers since the last 2-3 years.

Comment: I've just checked the documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html 
"This class is relatively expensive, because it adds a speculative layout pass before the final layout phase. Avoid using it where possible."
@CopsOnRoad: Thank you for your support. I will keep an eye on the performance of my app.

Comment: @MichaelS Yes, it is expensive (although it also breaks down to how many widgets you have and how you're laying them inside `IntrinsicHeight`). But that is the only way to answer your question besides giving a fixed height to your `Row`.

Comment: What if we're interested in clipping one child to the intrinsic height of the rest of the siblings?